# RSA Encrypt in javascript and decrypt in C# ,example?

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, rsa

I want to generate RSA keys in C# , put public key in hidden input field and store private key in session , on post form values will be encrypted with publickey and on server side form values will be decrypted using C# private key.
I went thru this 2 crypto libraries but both have example with encrypt/decrypt in JavaScript.

https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt -- supports open ssl PEM format key

and

https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico

I am getting 'length of the data to decrypt is not valid for the size of this key' exception on server side decryption.

// index.cshtml.cs

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        public string publickey;
        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
            {
                rsa.KeySize = 1024;
                publickey = Convert.ToBase64String(
                rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey());
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("privatekey", Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey()));
            }
        }

        public void OnPost(string emailaddress)
        {
           var key= HttpContext.Session.GetString("privatekey");
           int totalRead = 0;
           using (var rsa = RSA.Create())
           {
               rsa.KeySize = 1024;
               rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(Convert.FromBase64String(key)),out totalRead);
               var emailBytes= rsa.Decrypt(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(emailaddress), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
               ViewData["Email"]= System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(emailBytes);
           }
        }
    }
```

//index.cshtml

```
 @page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnKey" value="@Model.publickey"/>//saving public key here
    <form id="form1" method="post">
        <input id="email" type="email" name="emailaddress"/> 
        <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    <br/>
    Decrypted email:@ViewData["Email"]
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").submit(function(e) {
        var encrypted = cryptico.encrypt($('#email').val(),$('#hdnKey').val());
        console.log(encrypted);
        $('#email').val(encrypted.cipher);
    });

    });
    </script>
}
```

Included https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico/blob/master/cryptico.min.js in _layouts.cshtml

Comment: Any reason you're encrypting the form data? Does TLS not provide the required protection?

Comment: What do you see when you log `encrypted`? Is there a chance binary data is improperly converted to text?

Comment: @phuzi I can see encrypted text and success flag set to true in log. SSL cert is file on disk , and we download it from CA and i think it can be compromised.

Comment: I was asking to see what you see. Please include output in your question.

Comment: {status: 'success', cipher: 'JJ+E0vB0awiyxhyoCVZgS+686DD2tj5lHIrrse8ymueZS1B8sL…HfE=?oabnEdeZvZT/VQADSm+D7Gi7PxmXbNU6Y70H4I3MqQs='}

Comment: You are converting to binary from ASCII instead of performing base 64 decoding. In addition, for some reason there is a base64 padding character (`=`) in the middle for some reason or other. I don't know the cryptiko format, but knowing such is required to be able to decrypt if no direct library is available in C#.

Comment: [cryptico](https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico#encryption-1) uses hybrid encryption (RSA and AES), while the C# code performs pure RSA decryption. So currently both codes are not compatible.